# mongodb mongoose full join on array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have twoo collections I would like to preform a 'join' on. 
The first one who has the reference is parrent. 
The second one is calld child

This is how the object parrent looks like:

```
{
    "_id": "id_123"
    "name": "name",
    "children": ["id_child_1", "id_child_2", ...]
}
```

model/par.js looks like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Par= mongoose.model('parrent',new mongoose.Schema({}), 'parrent');

exports.Par= Par;
```

route/par.js looks like this:

```
const {Par} = require('../models/par'); 
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const par = await Par.find();
    res.send(par);
  });

module.exports = router
```

The route child and model child looks exactly the same.
(This is a simplefied version of the case).

I would like to return something like this:

```
{
    "_id": "id_123"
    "name": "name",
    "children": [{"name":"child1"}, {"name":"child2"}, ...]
}
```

I couldn't find a solution that worked, is not depricated, or one that uses this architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood correctly you can get it using simply a `$lookup` like this:

```
db.parent.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "child",
      "localField": "children",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "children"
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hWyTJzThM5N)

Or using `$project` to not output the `_id` in children array: [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LxCS5jZVfzp)

Comment: I found this but I don't understand where the db (from db.parent) commes. Is it suposed to be mongoose? I get the parrents like this: ``const par = await Dos.find()`` and for the children its like: ``const child = await Child.find()``.

Comment: You create a model for the parent and another for the children, right? Is that because you can do `Child.find()`. So in the file where you export the children model, you also declare the collection name. So that's the name you can use. By default (if third parameter is empry) the collection will be the name in plural. [Docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html)